# If $\|f\|_3 = \|g\|_3 = \int_E f^2 g =1,$ prove that $g(x) = |f(x)|$ for almost all $x \in E.$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

> **Question**: Let $E$ be a measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $f,g \in L^3(E)$ satisfying the  following equality 
>   $$\|f\|_3 = \|g\|_3 = \int_E f^2 g =1.$$
>   Prove that 
>   $$g(x) = |f(x)|$$ 
>   for almost all $x \in E.$

My attempt:

By Holder's inequality, the integral $\int_E f^2g$ is defined.

I would like to show that the set $\{x\in E: g(x)=|f(x)|\}$ has measure zero.

By assumption, we have 
$$\int_E |f|^3 = 1, \int_E |g|^3 = 1 \text{ and } \int_E f^2g = 1.$$
Denoting 
$$\{x\in E: g(x) = |f(x)|\} = \{g = |f|\},$$
by additivity of integration, we have 
$$1 = \int_E |f|^3 = \int_{\{g=|f|\}}|f|^3 + \int_{\{g\neq |f|\}}|f|^3,$$
$$1 = \int_E |g|^3 = \int_{\{g=|f|\}}|f|^3 + \int_{\{g\neq |f|\}}|g|^3,$$
and 
$$1 = \int_E f^2 g = \int_{\{g=|f|\}}|f|^3 + \int_{\{g\neq |f|\}}f^2 g.$$
It follows that 
$$\int_{\{g\neq |f|\}}|f|^3 = \int_{\{g\neq |f|\}}|g|^3,$$
$$ \int_{\{g\neq |f|\}}|g|^3= \int_{\{g\neq |f|\}}f^2 g$$
and 
$$\int_{\{g\neq |f|\}}|f|^3 = \int_{\{g\neq |f|\}}f^2 g.$$
However, I could not proceed from here.
Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Your argument does not work. Look at Wikipedia for condition for equality in Holder's inequality.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy We do not know if $g \geq 0$, so a priori, it could be true that $\int |f^2g|>1$, then one may not apply the condition for equality in Holder, I think.

Comment: If you start with $1 \leq \int f^{2} |g|$ and then apply Holder you will see that the hypothesis holds with $g$ changed to $|g|$ so you can apply condition for equality in Holder.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I completely agree with you (but you did not specify that before).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints: Recall Young's inequality which says that if $p^{-1}+q^{-1}=1$, then $ab\leq \frac{a^p}{p}+\frac{b^q}{q}$, for all $a,b\geq 0$. Moreover, equality holds iff $a^p=b^q$.

Applying this with $a=|f|^2, b=|g|, p=3/2,q=3$ and then integrating both sides, we find that $$\int |f^2g| \leq \frac{2}{3}\int|f|^3+\frac{1}{3}\int|g|^3=1=\int f^2g \leq \int |f^2g|,$$ so all of the inequalities are equalities. Deduce that $f^2g= |f^2g| = \frac{2}{3}|f|^3+\frac{1}{3}|g|^3$ a.e. Now apply the condition for equality to hold in Young's inequality, then deduce that $g$ must be nonnegative on $E$ a.e.

Comment: I understand the equality $f^2 g = |f^2 g|.$ But how to obtain that $|f^2g| = \frac{1}{3} |f|^3 + \frac{2}{3} |g|^3?$ We are using the fact that if $h$ is nonnegative on $E,$ then $\int_E |h|=0$ if and only if $h=0$ a.e. on $E,$ right?

Comment: @Idonknow If $f_1,f_2$ are integrable functions such that $f_1 \leq f_2$ and $\int f_1=\int f_2$, then $f_1=f_2$ a.e.

Comment: By the way, I think there is a typo. Do you mean $p = \frac{3}{2}$ and $q = 3?$

Comment: Ya for sure ofc

Comment: May I know what is next after showing that $g$ is nonnegative a.e. on $E?$

Comment: Nothing, then you're done.

Comment: Why would $g$ is nonnegative a.e. on $E$ implies that $g=|f|$ a.e. on $E?$

Comment: When you apply the condition for equality to hold in young's inequality, what do you get?

Comment: Ooh yeah, we get $|f|^3 = |g|^3.$ So $|f| = |g|.$ But $g$ is nonnegative a.e. on $E,$ therefore $|f| = g$ a.e. on $E.$ Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that's all